# Data delivered on s3 by kinesis firehose are versioned, how to desactivate that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

After investigating because I was enable to delete data on s3 using that command:

`S3_CLIENT.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=Key)`

I have found that Kinesis Firehose was by default versioning data files on my bucket, what is thee reason for that ? And is there any simple way to desactivate it ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**: I forgot to specify that bucket versioning is not activated on my bucket

Comment: Your bucket has versioning enabled. You can go to your bucket and suspend it.

Comment: sorry, I must have specified that. The thing is that versioning is desactivated on my bucket and yet everything behave like it's activate

Answer (score 0):

This is within the S3 bucket.

You will need to disable bucket versioning: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html